# No able to add custom scope in AWS Pre-Token Generation trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have AWS Cognito user pool with one Allowed custom scopes for my app client i.e. `admin-only`. I have two kinds of users `1. Users in Admin Group 2. Non-Admins users`. For my one of the AWS API Gateway Routes, I need to deny the access if user from non admin group is hitting the API Url, basically its allowed only for users which are part of Admin User group.

I can achieve it through adding an `Authorization scope` on API gateway route with this custom scope and then adding a scope manually when I request an Authorization token in Hosted UI popup. But in my app, I don't want to add this scope manually, rather want to add this scope when the token is generated. I explored `Pre-Token Generation Trigger` but not able to see the way to override or add `scope` attribute in it?

Question is, is there a way to add/override custom scope in pre-token generation trigger ? If yes then how ? But if there is no way, then how to solve my use case ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the claimsToAddOrOverride attribute in the response to replace the scopes value returned in the token with anything you want, BUT you cannot see the existing values in the lambda it seems so would need to know the full set of values up front